# How to change the gitlab-runner long build path

Tags: reactjs, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd, gitlab-runner

I have a React.js project auto deployed on my digital ocean droplet using gitlab-runner, everything's working fine, but the project is always pulled on a long path, example :

> /home/gitlab-runner/builds/FiRsT_ToKeN_ChAraCters/0/mygitlab_username/my_project_name

I have tried to change the build dir editing the `config.toml` file in: /etc/gitlab-runner, but it changes only the builds directory, i want my path to look like :

> /home/gitlab-runner/customName/my_project_name

Comment: What executor are you using for your runner? It sounds like you ma be using a shell runner, at which point multiple jobs needs to be differentiated by the job path.

Comment: you are right, i'm using a shell executor

Comment: You should maybe take a look at the feature [runners.custom_build_dir](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runnerscustom_build_dir-section). But I'm not sure will do what you're asking for.

Comment: @AchrafBoutahar - you won't be able to get the clean build directory that you're looking for with a shell executor, only with a docker executor. The reason for this is that if the executor pulls down multiple jobs at a time, it needs to have a way of differentiating the root directories for each of those jobs. That's why you're getting the tokens and "0" in the path. If you need a clean directory, I'd recommend you use a docker executor.